# Как сделать update npm и node?

Tags: node.js, npm

Сейчас у меня  npm  версия 6.0.0 и node версия  v8.11.1.

Как сделать update npm ?

Как сделать update node.js ?

Comment: Для этого используется `nvm`

Comment: Что такое nvm  и как его использовать в моем случаи